# Get custom xml node value of log4net config in AdjustFileBeforeAppend method in C#

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, log4net, configuration-files

I have log4net configuration as below:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="TestAppender"
type="myLogging.Program+RollingFileCustomAppender" >
  <file value="C:\Users\john\Desktop\myLogging\MyTestAppender.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
  <newNode value="23"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="1KB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{3} - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="All" />
</root>
```

Here, in the configuration I added a new xml node named as **newNode**. 
I also created a customized file appender:

```
    public class RollingFileCustomAppender: RollingFileAppender
    {
        public RollingFileByMaxAgeAppender()
          : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
        {
            // how to access the new node value here?????????
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to get the new node value in **AdjustFileBeforeAppend** method in c#?

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property getter and setter to your custom `RollingFileAppender` class.
The name of this property can be in PascalCase.
It can be of type `String` or even numeric, eg. `Int32`.

For the appender in your question it will look like:

```
public class RollingFileCustomAppender: RollingFileAppender
{
    public Int32 NewNode { get; set; }

    protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
    {
         // Do something with this.NewNode
    }

    // ...
}
```